# Smaller than a continent, bigger than a country

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a geographical landmass which is bigger than a single nation but smaller than a continent.

"Region" is not acceptable - I am using that already to define a much smaller area, so can't use it.

For example, this word will describe these types of landmasses:

- East Coast (US + Canada)
- Western Europe
- Alpine Region
- South East Asia
- ASEAN
- Korean Peninsula

### Why?

I am designing an information system that deals with geographical regions of varying sizes.

- World
- Continent
- ? <- this is the word I am looking for
- Country
- Region (this is for state, province, city, town, village, suburb, borough, and everything in between)

## Options

The only option I have is "[subcontinent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subcontinent)" - but I wish there was something better.

Comment: I wonder if you shouldn't make a distinction between *political* regions and *geographic* ones.

Comment: I have to. Because this information system concerns itself with supply chains.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "region" is the most commonly used term for that. Have you looked in a thesaurus? You'll find options such as "area" and "zone" that might work.

Comment: Region is a very vague term which can mean [a subarea within a country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Italy) or a [part of a continent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Europe). I suspect you'll find the same problem with most alternatives. Use subcontinent.

Comment: You might want to ask on a computing/database or GIS Stack Exchange how this is handled by other people. You'll almost certainly get better advice.

Comment: @StuartF - I'm not sure that the East Coast (US + Canada),
the Alpine region, ASEAN or the Korean Peninsula can be properly classed as a *subcontinent* (which usually refers to India and adjoining countries.

Comment: If they're defined by sociopolitical groupings (i.e, humans) you could call them _groupings_. If they're defined geologically, you could call them _plates_ or _plate assemblies_.

Comment: I think that 'region' is the most commonly used term. If you are at the design stage I suggest that you use 'area' for your smaller units and 'region' for the larger one. If the system is already partly implemented use 'area' for the larger one. I'd suggest that you don't use 'landmass' as,  to me that implies a large area of land with distinct boundaries and very specific characteristics.

Comment: You already have the answer: _subcontinent_. It is not clear what you mean by "something better". I don't believe there is something better, or in better words, something more apt and clear. Another option is neologizing your own word like _supercountry_, _megacountry_ or _multicountry_; but they are no better than _subcontinent_.

Comment: It seems that you are writing a document that has a stipulated terminology of its own, and that in the course of writing it you have decided to use *region* within the document in a particular way. Well and good, creating such a stipulatively defined terminology for use within a particular document is common and often useful. Your decision to use *region* in this way, however, now precludes you from using it for this other purpose, even though it would otherwise be the best word for it. How to solve that problem is a matter for you to decide; it is not matter of established usage.

Comment: You could use "area" because it can be just as vague as "region". Or you could use region twice and say something like "geographical region" and "local region" or something like that.

Comment: The usual thing is to have country under continent. That is just the way it is.

Comment: Note that ASEAN (Association of Southeast Asian Nations) contains several states which are islands or island groups, so it is not contained by any continent.

Comment: Are these regions mutually exclusive/unique?  Could you have East Coast  (US and Canada) as well as North America and East of the Mississippi?

Answer (score -1):

You may use **landmass**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landmass)
> *landmass*:
> a large area of land
> *continental landmasses*

Three examples plucked at random from the web are:

> [Geography](https://geography.name/kola-peninsula/)
> *Geographically, the Kola Peninsula forms the heel of the Scandinavian landmass*

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Albania)
> *Albania has a variety of climate systems. With its coastline facing the Adriatic and Ionian seas in the Mediterranean sea, its highlands backed upon the elevated Balkan landmass, ...*

> [DSFL](https://www.dsfl.in/korean-language-aroun-the-world/)
> *Korean (Hankukmal) is the language of the Korean landmass in upper east Asia.*

In each example the area referred to comprises more than one country but does not extend to a whole continent, although the term is also used for that purpose.

Comment: The problem is that the OP has not stated if, as Hot Licks mentions, they are interested in political, geographic, or economic areas.

Comment: @Greybeard I see no problem; the question says “geographic”.

Comment: @Anton But OP acknowledges in the response to a comment that political jurisdictions must be considered because he’s working on supply chains.

Comment: @Anton, take note of the OP's examples: it would be very odd to refer to the East Coast of North America or to Western Europe as distinct landmasses.

Comment: What about "Colorado landmass"? It is smaller than Country.

Comment: Adducing or imagining particular examples of landmass that writer feels inappropriate does not refute the general definition in Merriam Webster and in other dictionaries (not that they agree perfectly), nor does it invalidate the many geographical or technical uses of landmass to be found in literature and online. It is pointless to argue each case; for each one there are other valid ones to be found in online and technical usage. The term is not exactly defined but it fits the PO request because of the many examples to be found like the three I quote. The site cannot accommodate hundreds!